# $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^2-\overline{z}}{|z|}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^2-\overline{z}^2}{|z|}$$

If we suppose $z = x+iy$, then the limit becomes:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2-y^2+2xyi-(x-yi)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2-y^2+2xyi-x^2+2xyi+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{4ixy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \infty$$

Am I right?

Comment: You can't be right, because

$$ |z^2 - \overline{z}^2|/|z| = 4 |\Im(z)| |\Re(z)|/|z| $$

letting $z = it$ and $z = t$, we see that the limit approaches zero from the imaginary and real axis. In your limit, $xy$ converges to zero much faster than $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\le \frac12\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: As simple as it gets. +1  Important that the OP can appreciate the simplicity that *sometimes* exists in mathematics.

Comment: @DonAntonio Much appreciative my friend!